# On presence receiving published item twice ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I am developing a xmpp client and currently working on "pubsub".
I created a node in pubsub and subscribed two users to it.
But when a subscriber login(show presence) i get the last published item twice.
I am using ejabberd server.
Can anyone help??
Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve this?. My issue is related. I am receiving presence stanza twice.

Comment: No i could'nt....but check with the latest version of ejabberd.

Answer (score 0):

Same here,

There seems to be two different queues. With *notification_type=normal*, messages are stored offline. When receiver becomes online, it receives the message twice:

- from offline spool, without headline attribute
- from pubsub send loop (as node is still configured with send_last_published_item = on_sub_and_presence)

As stated [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/827) when configuring pubsub node with *notification_type=normal*, it's best to disable send_last_published_item or set it to on_sub only in order to avoid receiving the message twice.